# Is TransPort deprecated? If not, what are recommended use cases?

Tags: socks, pluggable-transports, transparent-proxy

I've gotten the sense that using `TransPort` as a transparent proxy is more-or-less deprecated, vs using application-specific `SocksPort` and, if necessary, `torsocks`. Is that correct?

If not, what are recommended use cases for `TransPort`?

What are the key considerations?

Also, I must say that `Pluggable Transport` and `TransPort` complicate searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point-of-view, `torsocks` and using `TransPort` selectively for some applications (e.g. like [Mike's suggested setup for Android](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/mission-impossible-hardening-android-security-and-privacy)) is quite equivalent.

Two key differences, though:

- `torsocks` will take care of DNS leaks, so extra care is needed when using `TransPort`.
- `torsocks` 2.0 will take care of filtering and blocking some network system calls. Again, it might be more straightforward than configuring the perfect firewall (hint: don't forget IPv6).

But in both cases, one can have a look at the application, what information it might be able to leak, and make an informed choice about routing its network traffic through Tor.

What is indeed now considered a bad idea is to route all traffic through Tor indiscriminately (using `TransPort`). Having some random update manager sends a unique hardware identifier through Tor might not be the best strategy for anonymity.